# Labelling spectrograms

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, preprocessing, audio-recognition, labelling

Currently I'm working on a ML project, just need an information, is there any tool that is present that can load audios file and generates spectrograms as well as an option to annotating/ label the spectrograms.

I have thousands of audio data to label; I've found a tool (audacity) but I need to load each audio file and it's not giving min and max frequency after exporting labels.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks